# What are the signs that a baby is too hot?

Tags: infant, temperatures

During summer, the room in which our 3 month old daughter sleeps frequently stays at around 22C (~72F) which is higher than we'd ideally like it to be. We are also swaddling her using a Summer Infant SwaddleMe cotton wrap. How can we tell if she is overheating at night without disturbing her?

Comment: I'm not a doctor, but if she's sweating, that's the first visible sign the body gives to most of us that we need to cool down.

Comment: In past years, we have kept our house at 78 during the hot summer months. Now that we have newborn in tow, we have bumped that down to 75 after a conversation with her doctor. After she had issues with temperature regulation in the hospital, I've become a bit obsessed about checking her frequently. Even with a layer of clothing and a swaddle at 75, she does not come close to over-heating. Her temperature is routinely smack in the middle of the ideal zone (98.3-98.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following, taken together, can help indicate overheating.  None of these alone fully diagnose overheating, but taken together they can suggest whether you should take further action or not.

Signs of overheating in infants:

- Sweating, which can be felt as dampness around the neck or head
- Red face or rash on face
- Rapid breathing
- Feels warm to the touch (head or chest)
- Restlessness

It may be that a temporal thermometer, with a light touch on the forehead, will not disturb your child.  If so this can also be used to understand if they are overheating.